# Vulnerabilidad de lo4j en Genexus?

Tags: java, genexus, log4j

Está circulando información sobre vulnerabilidades de la librería LOG4J entre versiones de 2.0 a 2.14.

GX17 update5 incorpora la versión log4j 2.13, ¿podría ser que los proyectos desarrollados con geNexus se vean vulnerables?

Alguien alguna otra información amplia.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: La forma de probarlo es relativamente simple y hay varias pruebas de concepto. Tienes que ver si, al enviarle algo que la app imprima en los logs, puedes hacer que procese el recurso JNDI e intente conectarse externamente. Revisa si hay información de quienes mantienen Genexus.

Answer (score 4):

Hay más información en este link de Genexus: https://www.genexus.com/en/developers/websac?data=50554

Por lo que veo solo aplica para aplicaciones Java

Comment: En efecto, depende de la forma en la que log4j-core interactúa con JNDI en Java.

Answer (score 1):

La situación con Log4j es global y aun están en análisis tal cual lo detallan
https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-44228
https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-45046

Un resumen bastante claro del problema está en este video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGIH3ulSk-Q

Desde Genexus se está manteniendo la información actualizada en el SAC que menciona Mateo (https://www.genexus.com/developers/websac?data=50554) así que de pronto es bueno suscribirse al mismo.

Este es el link del proveedor de la biblioteca está publicando: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/index.html y su recomendación (actual) es actualizar a 2.16.

Comment: Gus...y como nos suscribimos al mismo al SAC. Me loqueé con mi cuenta de Genexus pero no me sale ninguna opción para ello. Gracias!

Comment: Mateo: en el link del SAC abajo aparecen los productos/versiones que afecta y ahi podés suscribirte (si estás logueado, sino te pide login)

Comment: Para ejecutar Deploy Application en genexus, sigue solicitando log4j-api-2.13.3.jar log4j-core-2.13.3.jar, no las pude eliminar. Por lo cual solamente en el .war  le estoy quitando y colocando las librerias log4j-api-2.16.0.jar log4j-core-2.16.0.jar

Comment: Margarita: si, en el JAR que arma para el deployment siempre incluye esas. El único modo que encontré (hasta ahora) es el que  tu mencionas: remplazarlas en el JAR que arma.

Comment: Ahora si salió la opción de suscribir al SAC. Antes no salía. Gracias Gus.

Comment: Margarita: hay una forma mejor que es editar el  JavaLibs.targets (ejemplo:
C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus17u6\gxjava\JavaLibs.targets) y sustituir ahi la versión de log4j.
En el SAC se explica mejor: https://www.genexus.com/developers/websac?data=50554

Answer (score 0):

Ojo, se encontró otra vulnerabilidad de nivel **Alta**, en la versión 2.16, (la anterior era nivel **crítica**).

Por lo que a partir del día 18 de diciembre recomiendan usar la versión 2.17, esto en el SAC no lo han mencionado (hoy 20/12/21), pero recomiendo echarle un vistazo diario directamente a la página de log4j https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html, este link viene también en el SAC.

En resumen la versión 2.16, si resuelve la vulnerabilidad detectada el 9 de diciembre. Pero se ha encontrado que esta versión tiene una vulnerabilidad distinta, por lo que se subsana con la versión 2.17. Y se recomienda estar monitoreando cada día por si se encontrarán nuevas. Esperemos que no.

Comment: En Gx17 u7 lo tienen solucionado

Comment: Acabo de actualizar Gx17 U7, revisé la carpeta lib,  aun se encuentran log4j-1.2-api-2.16.0.jar  , log4j-api-2.16.0.jar.  Debido a que es una aplicación web interna ¿pienso que no correría tanto riesgo si la dejo con esta versión?

Comment: Pude solucionar con este link https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?49844,How+to+update+log4j+jars